# using in_array in foreach and take out array have matching value

Tags: php

I am having issues with using `in_array()` inside a `foreach` loop. I have an array like this

```
[0] =>
    name=>1
    type=>foo
[1] =>
    name=>2
    type=>bar
[2] =>
    name=>3
    type=>bar
[3] =>
    name=>4
    type=>foo
```

I'm using

```
if(in_array('foo',$array->type){ *my echo code*}
```

to take out all array that have `type = foo` but it also take out unmatch array. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are doing it incorrectly..

```
foreach($yourarr as $k=>$arr)
{
 if(in_array('foo',$arr))
 {
   echo key($arr); //"prints" name , name
 }
}
```

[<kbd>Working Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/137878)

Comment: well, i just found out where problem is. At first i coding exactly like you but i defined values instead of echo it. btw tks u

Comment: @ŌkamiXOukarin, Glad :) anytime.

Answer (score 1):

in your case `$array->type` is not an array. it is a string.
you should compare it like string comparison.

```
if('foo' === $array['type']){ *my echo code*}
```

you also change array access.

Comment: $array['type'] not $array->type surely?

Answer (score 0):

You need array syntax and comparison:

```
if('foo' == $array['type']) {
  /* your code */
}
```